# Arduino Connect to Mysql Using USB

Tags: c#, c++, mysql, arduino

I'm trying to connect the arduino uno r3 direct to mysql database using only USB. I don't know what is the problem with this code so I ask anyone to help me how to connect the mysql to arduino. I already used the example provided by mysql but didn't work and I try so many examples releated to the topic but all of them didn't work.

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <sha1.h>
#include <mysql.h>

/* Setup for Ethernet Library */
byte mac_addr[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
IPAddress server_addr(127,0,0,1);
IPAddress ip(192,168,1,177);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
char sqlbuf[128];
char sqlDbase[] = " USE arduinodb";


unsigned int mysqlPort=3307;
Connector my_conn; // The Connector/Arduino reference
char user[] = "arduinodb";
char password[] = "arduinodb";
boolean sqlconnect= false;


void setup() 
{
  Ethernet.begin(mac_addr);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(350);
  Serial.println("connecting MySQL Server..");

 if (my_conn.mysql_connect(server_addr, mysqlPort, user, password))
  {
   sqlconnect=true;
   Serial.println("Query Success!");
    delay(150);
    my_conn.cmd_query(sqlDbase); 
   }
 else
  {
   Serial.println("Connection failed.");
  }
}



void loop() 
{
if (sqlconnect==true)
{
"INSERT INTO testingtbl (id, percentage, score)values('','50','50') ";
my_conn.cmd_query(sqlbuf);
Serial.print("Data stored!\n");
delay(150);
}
else
{
Serial.print("failed");
delay(1000);
}
}
```

Comment: What do you mean using USB? Your code is trying to use Ethernet. And what has this to do with C#?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure Ethernet-over-USB is on on the system you're connecting to
2. Make sure you set up the route from your adapter to wherever the DB server is.

As you're c-sharping, I presume you use Win.
Then check for keyword "RNDIS" over I-net.